# Windows Azure, Servicestack on Asp can't map post mutipart data

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, servicestack

I have a servicestack web service which run on an ASP website, hosted on Windows Azure.
When I perform a POST request with multipart data, the website is unable to map the data.

This problem only occurs when I request the website on Windows Azure. It work perfectly on my local machine.

Here is my code to request the server:

```
public async Task<Image> CreateAsync(Image image, byte[] data)
    {
        // Define Content.
        var json = image.ToJson();
        var token = ServiceLocator
            .Retrieve<IAuthenticationService>()
            .Authentication
            .Token;

        // Sending request.
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient
                .DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            using (var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(data))
            {
                using (var postContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    postContent.Add(new StringContent(token), "Token");
                    postContent.Add(new StringContent(json), "Json");
                    postContent.Add(imageContent, "File", "test.jpg");

                    string uri = General.Domain + "/image";
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, postContent);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    image = Image.FromJson(json);
                    return image;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does somebody already encoutered this problem ?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Actualy there is no error message. The error is that it doesn't map anything on Windows Azure. My web service throw an exception cause the Token is empty. I tried with Json and File, they are also empty. When I run the web service on local, everything is fine, and the job is done. I wonder if i have to specify something in the header of the request or if it is a bug of Azure.